# Jenkins Copy Artifact - does not copy any files

Tags: jenkins

I am using copy artifact 1.46 in Jenkins 2.263.4 and want to copy a file from one job to another. However, it fails to do so. The error is always:

```
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from TestPack with filter: **
```

Have tried this with both a scripted pipeline job and a freestyle one, on both Windows and Centos, but same result. I know it has found the job, because I get an error if the job name if wrong. The job I want to copy from only has a single text file in its root directory.

My pipeline script is:

```
node ("${env.Node}") {
    
    stage('dodeploy') { 
      copyArtifacts(projectName: 'TestPack');
    }

}
```

I have tried `copyArtifacts` with and without a filter and with and without a target. In the freestyle project I tried similar settings settings, but get exactly the same error.

Feel I must be missing something obvious, but cannot see what.

Comment: What command are you executing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was not interpreting the 'Artifacts' part of 'copyArtifacts' literally enough. It looks as though copyArtifacts can only copy files that have previously been archived in a post build step (or pipeline stage).